# ¿ListView en tipo Fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-fragment

Tengo esto para crear un ListView determinado:

El problema es que es un *Fragment*, y al ejecutar la aplicación y pinchar en dicho *Fragment*, se me detiene y se me sale, no se muestra nada. ¿Qué falla?

*"First_fragment.java"*:

```
public class First_fragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView lista1;
    public final static String CLAVE_EXTRA_PASAR2 = "true";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_tab,container,false);

            ArrayList<Lista_entrada> datos = new ArrayList<>();

            datos.add(new Lista_entrada(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stopwatch),"TENIS", "Iluminacion de las pistas 1 - 5"));
            datos.add(new Lista_entrada(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stopwatch),"PADEL", "Iluminacion de las pistas 1 - 7"));
            datos.add(new Lista_entrada(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stopwatch),"FRONTON", "Activar o desactivar iluminacion"));
            datos.add(new Lista_entrada(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stopwatch),"FUTBOL", "Activar o desactivar iluminacion"));
            datos.add(new Lista_entrada(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stopwatch),"CLUB SOCIAL", "Iluminacion por zonas"));

            lista1 = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mylist);

            //Esto es para el cuadradito que te dice lo que has elegido.

            lista1.setAdapter(new Lista_adaptador(getActivity(), R.layout.boton_main, datos, null){ // list_main donde aparecera
                @Override
                public void onEntrada(Object entrada, View view) {
                    if (entrada != null) {
                        TextView texto_superior_entrada = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                        if (texto_superior_entrada != null)
                            texto_superior_entrada.setText(((Lista_entrada) entrada).get_textoEncima());

                        TextView texto_inferior_entrada = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                        if (texto_inferior_entrada != null)
                            texto_inferior_entrada.setText(((Lista_entrada) entrada).get_textoDebajo());

                    }
                }
            });
            lista1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> pariente, View view, int posicion, long id){

                    Lista_entrada elegido = (Lista_entrada) pariente.getItemAtPosition(posicion);

                    if(posicion == 0){
                        Intent intencion3 = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Antonio.class);
                        intencion3.putExtra(CLAVE_EXTRA_PASAR2, "true");
                        startActivity(intencion3);
                    }
                    else if(posicion == 1){
                        Intent intencion4 = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Antonio.class);
                        intencion4.putExtra(CLAVE_EXTRA_PASAR2, "true");
                        startActivity(intencion4);
                    }
                    else if(posicion == 2){
                        Intent intencion5 = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Antonio.class);
                        intencion5.putExtra(CLAVE_EXTRA_PASAR2, "true");
                        startActivity(intencion5);
                    }
                    else if(posicion == 3){
                        Intent intencion6 = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Antonio.class);
                        intencion6.putExtra(CLAVE_EXTRA_PASAR2, "true");
                        startActivity(intencion6);
                    }
                    else if(posicion == 4){
                        Intent intencion7 = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Antonio.class);
                        intencion7.putExtra(CLAVE_EXTRA_PASAR2, "true");
                        startActivity(intencion7);
                    }
                }
            });
        return v;
    }
}
```

*"Lista_entrada.java"*:

```
public class Lista_entrada {

    private String textoEncima;
    private String textoDebajo;
    private Drawable icono_deportes;

    public Lista_entrada (Drawable icono_deportes, String textoEncima, String textoDebajo) {
        super();
        this.textoEncima = textoEncima;
        this.textoDebajo = textoDebajo;
        this.icono_deportes = icono_deportes;
    }

    public String get_textoEncima() {
        return textoEncima;
    }

    public String get_textoDebajo() {
        return textoDebajo;
    }

    public Drawable get_icono_deportes(){
        return icono_deportes;
    }
}
```

*Lista_Adaptador*:

```
public abstract class Lista_adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<?> entradas;
    private int R_layout_IdView;
    private Context contexto;


    public Lista_adaptador(Context contexto, int R_layout_IdView, ArrayList<?> entradas, Activity activity) {
        super();
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.entradas = entradas;
        this.R_layout_IdView = R_layout_IdView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int posicion, View view, ViewGroup pariente) {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R_layout_IdView, null);
        }

        onEntrada (entradas.get(posicion), view);
        Lista_entrada dir = (Lista_entrada) entradas.get(posicion);
        ImageView icono_deportes = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icono_deportes);
        icono_deportes.setImageDrawable(dir.get_icono_deportes());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return entradas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int posicion) {
        return entradas.get(posicion);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int posicion) {
        return posicion;
    }

    /** Devuelve cada una de las entradas con cada una de las vistas a la que debe de ser asociada
     * @param entrada La entrada que sera la asociada a la view. La entrada es del tipo del paquete/handler
     * @param view View particular que contendra los datos del paquete/handler
     */
    public abstract void onEntrada (Object entrada, View view);
}
```

*"activity_profesorado.xml"*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*boton_main.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/stopwatch"
            android:id="@+id/icono_deportes" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ¿Que error te aparece en la consola?

Comment: intenta cambiando.. lista1 = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mylist);
 en vez de getActivity() cámbialo por el la instancia de tu View que es "v" en todos los casos

Comment: sale esto, error404, FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
                         at com.prueba.rudeboys.rudeboys1.First_fragment.onCreateView(First_fragment.java:70)
                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)

Comment: y sigue con esto: at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)

Comment: ¿ Qué puede ser ? voy a probar eso, marlonpya EDIT: Me da fallo en algunos casos si pongo "v" .

Comment: @Error404 Te has fijado que es un tipo Fragment? Tiene algo que ver? Tengo un bottomBar con 5 fragments, y en uno quiero que haya una listview, si que es posible no?

Comment: @RfMvs El error que te da está en la linea 70 tal y como muestra tu consola. Ese error se debe a que está intentando acceder a algún elemento que no existe (o posición). Ahora no puedo mirarlo a fondo ya que estoy con un proyecto personal pero luego si tengo tiempo miro un poco más a fondo tu pregunta.

Comment: Linea 70 :  lista1.setAdapter(new Lista_adaptador(getActivity(), R.layout.boton_main, datos, null){

Comment: Vale, de acuerdo, estoy al tanto por si acaso, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es esto.

```
lista1 = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mylist);
```

Deberías tener esto:

```
lista1 = (ListView) **view**.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
```

Hazme saber si necesitas más ayuda y si ese no era el eroor. Saludos! Cualquier cosa que necesites a la orden :)